# A first order non-linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, homogeneous-equation, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm trying to solve this non-linear differential equation : 
$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{y^3}{(y+1)^2(y+2)^2} $$
with the boundary condition $y(x_0)=x_0$, $x>0$, and $y(x)$ being a positive function.

The equation may look simple to integrate, however after integration i get what looks like a transcendental equation and i can not isolate $y(x)$,
Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: It's certainly possible that $y(x)$ is not an elementary function which means that you can't express it unless you use special functions like the Lambert $W$ or infinite series. This doesn't mean that $y(x)$ doesn't exist, though.

Comment: @bjorn93 yes, that's definitely not an elementary function since after integration, the solutions are like roots of $ a log x +b x^2 + c x +d/x+ e/x^2 +f $ i couldn't write it as a function of Lambert  fct